# Ruby Azure Blob Storage: "RequestBodyTooLarge"

Tags: ruby, azure

If I try to upload a large file - 388.7 MB in this case - to azure blob storage using the demo code, it fails like so:

```
begin
  content = File.open("big_file.dat", "rb") { |file| file.read }
  blob = azure_blob_service.create_block_blob(container.name,"image-blob", content)
  puts blob.name
rescue StandardError => e
  $stderr.puts e.message
end

# RequestBodyTooLarge (413): The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit.
```

I've read in the blob storage documentation that blobs can be up to 200 GB in size, so it looks as though the Ruby API doesn't correctly chunk its file uploads. Am I missing something?

Comment: A few thoughts: What version of the Azure SDK for Ruby are you using? We're up to 0.6.4 at this time.  This sounds like an SDK bug, but hard to be sure.  The Ruby SDK implements the RESTful interface to Azure storage as detailed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135726.aspx.  You can clone the repo if you want to trace: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby.

Comment: I'm using 0.6.4 too. Will sit down and trace in next week, but it's the kind of thing I thought would just work - I thought maybe I was doing something wrong!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current Ruby Azure SDK does indeed have methods for doing chunked uploads, but there are no usage examples anywhere and everything in the specs is a mock, which doesn't really help.

Getting chunked uploads to work is so fiddly that this is absolutely something that should be included in the library. It took me a number of hours to get this right and I hope this code snippet helps.

Here is a very basic usage example:

```
class ::File
  def each_chunk(chunk_size=2**20)
    yield read(chunk_size) until eof?
  end
end

container  = 'your container name'
blob       = 'your blob name'
block_list = []
service    = Azure::BlobService.new
counter    = 1

open('path/to/file', 'rb') do |f|
  f.each_chunk {|chunk|
    block_id = counter.to_s.rjust(5, '0')
    block_list << [block_id, :uncommitted]

    # You will likely want to get the MD5 for retries
    options = {
      content_md5: Base64.strict_encode64(Digest::MD5.digest(chunk)),
      timeout:     300 # 5 minutes
    }

    md5 = service.create_blob_block(container, blob, block_id, chunk, options)
    counter += 1
  }
end

service.commit_blob_blocks(container, blob, block_list)
```

Give me a couple of days and I should have something more reasonably encapsulated committed to https://github.com/dmichael/azure-contrib

Answer (score 1):

Even though block blobs can be of 200 GB in size, you can upload a block blob without splitting it in chunks if the blob size is less than 64 MB. Any blob which is greater than this size must be uploaded by splitting it into chunks where each chunk can be of a maximum 4 MB in size.

Looking at the [`source code for this function`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/blob/master/lib/azure/blob/blob_service.rb#L581), this function uploads the file in one go without splitting it into chunks. Since your file size is more than 64 MB, you are getting this error. The solution would be to split your file in chunks and then upload the file using [`create_blob_block`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-ruby/blob/master/lib/azure/blob/blob_service.rb#L635) function.

Comment: Seems like the kind of thing the library should do for me. Thanks for the info!

Comment: I kind of both agree and disagree. IMHO, library should be smart enough to throw error from the client side itself that the file you're uploading is more than 64 MB but it should not split the file for you. That's something we as developers should control.

Comment: While chunking this is something that developers should be able to control, it is not unreasonable to expect a library function to handle chunked uploads. The fineuploader library for JavaScript offers this option and does not require the user to write chunking logic. All this being said, there is a real opportunity here for a pull request for the ultra-minimal Azure Ruby SDK