# "The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit" when uploading block blob to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-sdk-.net, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to upload a 300GB file to Azure Blob Storage. Below is the code that I am using:

```
// content = array of bytes ~ 300 GB
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(content))
{
      var blobRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions
      {
          ParallelOperationThreadCount = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.Constants.MaxParallelOperationThreadCount
      };
      blob.UploadFromStream(stream, options: blobRequestOptions);
}
```

This operation fails with the following message error:

> The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit

Comment: [The duplicate here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23567724/ruby-azure-blob-storage-requestbodytoolarge) is about ruby, but the solution is the same: make chunks since Azure doesn't support large blobs...

Comment: I encountered at least 5 different answers and none of them worked for me. I'll give this one a try.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - that info is not true anymore: block blobs support up to 4.77TB.

Comment: Which version of the client library SDK are you using?

Comment: @DavidMakogon I think my problem was related to the SDK version. I was using 7.1.2. I have just switched to 8.1.1. I'll come back with the result in a few hours after the test has finished.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the issue (per comment confirming older SDK version) is the client SDK version number. Starting with v8.0, large ( 200GB -> 4.77TB) block blob sizes are supported (with blocks now up to 100MB, vs the old 4MB limit). The 50,000-block limit still applies (so, 100MB x 50,000 blocks provides the 4.77TB size).

Prior SDK versions were limited to 4MB blocks, and 200GB block blob size limit.

> Larger Block Blobs are supported by the most recent releases of the .NET Client Library (version 8.0.0), the Java Client Library (version 5.0.0), the Node.js Client Library (version 2.0.0) and the AzCopy Command-Line Utility (version 5.2.0). You can also directly use the REST API as always. Larger Block Blobs are supported by REST API version 2016-05-31 and later.

More info [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/general-availability-larger-block-blobs-in-azure-storage/).